# Dynamic default scopes in sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am building kind of multitenancy using sequelize.js. Technically I need to filter all queries by predefined column and dynamic value of the current context. General idea was to use `defaultScope` to filter out other contexts, something like:

```
var context = () => { return "some current context id"; }

connection.define('kid', {
  firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
  photoUrl: Sequelize.STRING,
  context: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    defaultValue: context // this part works, it accepts function
  }
}, {
  defaultScope: {
    where: {
      context: context // this does not work, it does not accept function and values is defined only once
    }
  }
});
```

However this does not work because `defaultScope` is defined on the application start.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: did you find any solution ? I am facing problem about how to pass the default scope value dynamically here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it will help, but you can override a model default scope anytime.

```
let defaultScope = {
  where: {
    context: ""
  }
};
defaultScope.where.context = context();
model.addScope('defaultScope',defaultScope,{override: true});
```

Comment: It is potential issue with shared state. I would like to avoid such code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Sequelize scopes are defined on the model but you need to apply the scope just before the query because that's when you have context such as the user and role.

Here's a slightly modified copy of the scope merge function from Sequelize which you can use in your hooks such as `beforeFind()`

```js
// Feel free to write a more fp version; mutations stink.
const {assign, assignWith} = require('lodash')
const applyScope = ({scope, options}) => {
    if (!scope) {
        throw new Error('Invalid scope.')
    }

    if (!options) {
        throw new Error('Invalid options.')
    }

    assignWith(options, scope, (objectValue, sourceValue, key) => {
        if (key === 'where') {
            if (Array.isArray(sourceValue)) {
                return sourceValue
            }
            return assign(objectValue || {}, sourceValue)
        }
        else if (['attributes', 'include'].indexOf(key) >= 0
            && Array.isArray(objectValue)
            && Array.isArray(sourceValue)
        ) {
            return objectValue.concat(sourceValue)
        }

        return objectValue ? objectValue : sourceValue
    })
}
```

In your model:

```js
 {
    hooks: {
        beforeFind(options) {
            // Mutates options...
            applyScope({
                scope: this.options.scopes.user(options.user)
                , options
            })
            return options
        }
    }
    , scopes: {
        user(user) {
            // Set the scope based on user/role.
            return {
                where: {
                    id: user.id
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Finally in your query, set an option with the context that you need.

```js
const user = {id: 12, role: 'admin'}
YourModel.findOne({
    attributes: [
        'id'
    ]
    , where: {
        status: 'enabled'
    }
    , user
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late here but scopes can take arguments if defined as functions. From documentation [Sequelize scope docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/scopes.html) if the scope is defined as

```js
scopes: {
    accessLevel (value) {
      return {
        where: {
          accessLevel: {
            [Op.gte]: value
          }
        }
      }
    }
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'project'
  }
```

you can use it like: `Project.scope({ method: ['accessLevel', 19]}).findAll();` where `19` is the dynamic value the scope will use.
As per `defaultScope` I'm not sure it can be defined as a function